# Google Autocomplete appears behind reactstrap modal

Tags: css, google-places-api, reactstrap

The following HTML code rests inside a Modal component provided by reactstrap.

```
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="address">Location*</label>
      <br />
      <input
        id="address"
        className={classes.WholeWidthInput + " " + classes.BorderOverride}
        type="text"
        onChange={this.handleFormChange.bind(this, "address")}
        onBlur={this.saveAddress.bind(this)}
        required
        placeholder="Find location"
        value={this.props.post.address}
      />{" "}
      <br />
    </div>
```

The following code hooks up the google places api with the above input element.

```
 handleGoogleSearchLoad = () => {   
     /* global google */
     var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
         new google.maps.LatLng(-90, -180),
         new google.maps.LatLng(90, 180)
     );
     var options = { bounds: defaultBounds, types: ['(cities)'] };

     const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("address"), options);
     autocomplete.setFields(['address_components', 'formatted_address', 'geometry']);
     this.setState({autocomplete});

 }
```

But the thing is the dropdown appears behind the modal when I type something into the form to search. I tried the .pac_container css suggestion but it didn't work or maybe I don't know where the css should have been used. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide a codesandbox or stackblitz so that we can reproduce this issue from our side?

Comment: I got the solution for it. Sorry to have left the question hanging around. The naming for the css file was wrong for me. I had it *.module.css instead of just *.css and that is why it wasn't working.

Comment: Glad to hear you found the issue! Thanks for your update.